# How can i prove this similar nesbitt inequality?

Tags: inequality

1.Let: $a,b,c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$.Prove that:

$\frac{a^3}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+a^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq \frac{3}{2}$

2. Let: $k \geq 0$. Prove that:

$\frac{a^{k+1}}{b^{k}+c^{k}}+\frac{b^{k+1}}{c^{k}+a^{k}}+\frac{c^{k+1}}{a^{k}+b^{k}}\geq \frac{3}{2}$

I try to use Cauchy-Schwarz and Chebyshev but they are not worked

In my C-S solution i try to use it directly
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+a^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum_{sym}a^2b}$$ Then I try $$2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq3\sum_{sym}a^2b;$$
I think this is rearrangement inequality but i can't do it.

Come to be Chebyshev, I suppose $a\geq b\geq c$ then have:
$$LHS\geq \frac{1}{3}(a^2+b^2+c^2)(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{c^2+a^2})\geq\frac{3(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)};$$
So i just need to prove
$$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq a^2+b^2+c^2$$ with $a+b+c=3$ then i stuck here

Comment: $(1)$  falls to Jensen's inequality with the right choice of convex function.  However for $(2)$, do the conditions $a, b, c>0$ and $a+b+c=3$ from $(1)$ continue to apply?  If not, even considering just positives, as $a, b, c = \epsilon \to 0$, the LHS of $(2)$ can get quite low.

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát Show me please, how exactly you tried to use C-S and Chebyshov?

Comment: Do it and I'll show my solution. Without showing attempts your topic would be deleted and I don't want that my solution would be deleted.

Comment: Of course thanks

Comment: In my C-S solution i try to use it directly

Comment: $\frac{a^3}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+a^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2+b^2}\geq\frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{\sum _{sym}a^2b}$ Then I try to prove: $2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2\geq 3\sum_{sym}^{}a^2b$; I think this is rearrangement inequality but i can't do it

Comment: Come to the Chebyshev, I suppose $a\geq b\geq c$ then have: $LHS\geq \frac{1}{3}(a^3+b^3+c^3)(\frac{1}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{1}{b^2+c^2}+\frac{1}{c^2+a^2})\geq \frac{3(a^3+b^3+c^3)}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)}$; So i just need to prove $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq a^2+b^2+c^2$ with $a+b+c=3$ then i stuck here

Comment: but if we don't have $a+b+c=3$ how can we prove the 1 and 2 problems

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát If we don't have $a+b+c=3$, so these inequalities are wrong. Try $a=b=c\rightarrow0^+$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Given that you made the edit to the question, I believe the final inequality should be $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 \geq a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ like OP stated in comments right?

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát **First inequality:**   
Write it as $3(a^3+b^3+c^3) \geq (a^2+b^2+c^2) (a+b+c)$, and apply AM-GM.
$\quad$ 
**Second inequality:**
Write it as $2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \geq (a+b+c)(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)$, and apply AM-GM. $\quad$ Give these a try.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Yes, you are right. I think, now it's not so relevant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}}{b^k+c^k}-\frac{3}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^{k+1}}{b^k+c^k}-\frac{a}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a((a^k-b^k)-(c^k-a^k))}{b^k+c^k}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a^k-b^k)\left(\frac{a}{b^k+c^k}-\frac{b}{a^k+c^k}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{(a^k-b^k)(a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}+c^k(a-b))}{b^k+c^k)(a^k+c^k)}\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

By Rearrangement $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}}{b^k+c^k}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}}{a^k+c^k}$$ and
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}}{b^k+c^k}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}}{a^k+b^k}.$$
Indeed, let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus, $$a^{k+1}\geq b^{k+1}\geq c^{k+1}$$ and $$\frac{1}{b^k+c^k}\geq\frac{1}{c^k+a^k}\geq\frac{1}{a^k+b^k},$$ which by Rearrangement says:
$$a^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{b^k+c^k}+b^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{c^k+a^k}+c^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{a^k+b^k}\geq a^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{a^k+c^k}+b^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{b^k+a^k}+c^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{c^k+b^k}$$ and $$a^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{b^k+c^k}+b^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{c^k+a^k}+c^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{a^k+b^k}\geq a^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{a^k+b^k}+b^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{b^k+c^k}+c^{k+1}\cdot\tfrac{1}{c^k+a^k}.$$
Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}}{b^k+c^k}\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^{k+1}}{a^k+b^k}+\frac{a^{k+1}}{a^k+c^k}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^{k+1}}{a^k+b^k}+\frac{b^{k+1}}{a^k+b^k}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^{k+1}+b^{k+1}}{a^k+b^k}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b}{2}=\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\frac{3}{2}.$$

Comment: thanks a lot it's so good

Comment: How are the first 2 inequalities true ? Can u add u little more explanation ? Thanks ! Cheers !

Comment: @Balaji sb I added something. See now.

Comment: Ah ! Nice ! Thanks ! i missed the ordering $a^{k+1} \geq b^{k+1} \geq c^{k+1}$. Stating that would have been enough. Thanks man !